# "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" with instafeed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [InstaFeed](http://instafeedjs.com/) to get images from Instagram and show them on a website.

Here's my code:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var feed = new Instafeed({
            get: 'tagged',
            tagName: 'test',
            clientId: '0000000000000000000',
            limit: 6,
            after: function () {
                var images = $("#instafeed").find('a');
                $.each(images, function(index, image) {
                    var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
                    $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
                    $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
                    $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
                    $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
                    $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
                    $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');
                });
            },
            template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>'
        });
        feed.run();

    </script>

    <div id="instafeed"></div>
```

I'm pretty new to JS and JQuery, but I'm not sure why I get this error. The error is on the following line:

> var images = $("#instafeed").find('a');

Comment: please include jquery <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes you need to tell the client side where to get JQuery from, if you open the console of the client (F12) and press on the console button you'll see the runtime can't understand what the "$" is all about.  JQuery defines the "$" to be "JQuery"...

Comment: @JohnPeters Please elaborate.

Comment: You need a <script> tag as shown by Sushil, you have to tell the client where the JQuery.js is located.

Comment: @JohnPeters Already updated with that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you don't have jQuery loaded.

Add the following before your script block

```
<script src="path to your jquery file"></script>
```

and change the path to point to the URL on your server where jQuery can be accessed.

Comment: Yup, jQuery doesn't come for free.

Comment: I'm sorry, JQuery was actually included. Updated my question now.

Comment: You might want to cross check if it's actually accessible at that url